# Redirect only from certain website

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm working on a .NET Framework website that is only opened from a redirect command. Is it possible to do that only if I redirect from a certain website?

For example, if I have a personal blog and I want to redirect users to a certain site, that site would only open if the previous website is one I can whitelist or something like that. 
If possible, I'd like to do it server side (the redirecting application is built in .NET Core 2.1)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, no. While you can use the `Referer` (historically mispelled) header, that header is not guaranteed to be present and can also be spoofed. In other words, if the client simply doesn't send the header, there's no way to know whether the user was redirected from your other site or not. Even if it *is* present, the client could have simply sent the header manually and completely bypassed your other site.

If the two sites are on the same domain or subdomains of the same domain, you can set a cookie at your other site that is then checked on the redirected site. However, the sites need to be able share cookies, which again, means same domain and both have data protections providers configured to utilize the same distributed store.

If you want to limit access the best and most fool-proof way is always going to be auth. Make them login at both points and you can ensure that no one can do anything you don't want them to do.

Comment: Thank you very much